# NSDateFormatter giving incorrect output with am/ pm

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Below is what I am using

```
NSString *myDate = @"01-11-2014 10:22 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate *newDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDate];
NSLog(@"new date===%@=====%@", newDate, myDate);
```

Below is what I am getting

```
new date===2014-11-01 19:22:00 +0000=====01-11-2014 10:22 PM
                      ^^
```

Output I was expecting is

```
new date===2014-11-01 22:22:00 +0000=====01-11-2014 10:22 PM
                      ^^
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

---

When I have AM I have below output

```
new date===2014-11-01 07:22:00 +0000=====01-11-2014 10:22 AM
                      ^^
```

---

### Edit 1

Actually what I am doing is asked date and time in UITextField (sadly but true as client wanted it in same way)... and then concatenating this string and converting it to NSDate.

So what I have is

```
 NSString myDate = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%@ %@", appDate, appTime];
```

Comment: Seems like it's a time zone issue to me. Does your myDate have a time zone?

Comment: @Jamie : No, its just a string..

Comment: This isn't a time zone issue, it's correct. If you use `NSLog()`, the date's `-description` method will be used to format the date. And its implementation uses UTC, not the local time zone. The date you specify with your string probably is 19:22 in UTC.

Comment: Right..so you're getting the time from somewhere that already has the time zone calculated into it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell : thanks for your many many many.... :D

Comment: @Jamie : I was worried for NSLog, but the reminder in my app is going proerly... it was just NSDate formatter was using UTC and hence showing 3 hrs difference..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line of code:

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
```

You probably had the wrong timezone. You have to set the timezone to your timezone.

Comment: I think you should explain the issue.